# Finding the center of mass of a lamina

Tags: calculus, integration, multiple-integral

I was given the following problem:

> Find the mass and center of mass of a lamina bounded by $y=x^4 \text{ and } y=x^2, \rho\left(x,y\right)=4$

Trying to graph these bounds gave me this image:
[image]

Assuming the lamina is in the area within the bounds - meaning the two banana-shaped areas, I would guess the center of mass is $\frac13$. But that is not the case. I will attach my work, but am I misinterpreting the picture?

[image]

Thank you!

EDIT:
It has been pointed out that my bounds of integration for y are flipped. This is true, and when corrected, the mass is the same number, just positive. The center of mass is still in the same place.

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense that your mass is negative.  This comes from your incorrect bounds: the graph of $x^4$ is below that of $x^2$.

Comment: @Mnifldz see edit

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/CenterOfMass.aspx I tried to do the calculation as per pauls notes (my physics is rusty ) and I put this into Mathematica Integrate[(15/8)*(x^4 - x^8), {x, -1, 1}], which gives me 1/3 as well. So if you do find the error in the end then kindly post.]

Comment: @SagarM I haven't found the error - perhaps it is correct?

Comment: In my opinion, it is!

Comment: Reading other comments I just realized that the doubt you are facing is if the COM can lie outside the body itself. And the answer is it can. As @Mnifldz says COM is a theoretical abstraction and it can lie in all sorts of places, for example, I am quite sure that COM of Earth-Sun system is within Sun! Your question gave the appearance that your answer was not matching with the solution manual, So I asumed there are calculation issues

Comment: @SagarM Thank you! I see how my question was misleading. Thank you for your criticism!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is right in magnitude but the point $A$ must lie at (0,1/3). The limits you have put on the $y$ axis must be reversed. This is because on the interval $x \in [-1,1]$, $x^4 \leq x^2$. Hope it helps!

Comment: I do not understand what you mean in this answer.

Comment: @Burt He means that the center of mass is a *coordinate*, it's not a single number.  The center of mass is given by $(\overline{x}, \overline{y})$.  Saying "the center of mass is $\frac{1}{3}$" doesn't make sense.  It also sounds like he's pointing out what I had said in the comments above ($x^4$ should be your lower bound and $x^2$ is your upper bound).

Comment: @Mnifldz whoops, my bad. But, I do want to know how the point can be all the way at (0,1\3) when that doesn't seem to be part of the lamina

Comment: @Burt That’s kind of the point.  The center of mass is a theoretical value.  For instance, if you threw this object and wanted to track its kinematics as a point particle, you’d use the center of mass to track its central position with time (even though the object in real life might rotate wildly around the center of mass).  I think of you go to YouTube you can find good demonstrations of how objects rotate about their CM, even if it lies outside the object itself.

Comment: @Mnifldz That makes sense! I wasn't thinking about it like that - but now I see it. It's the point the object would rotate around - and when it is actually on the object it is the place where it would balance.